# Practical solution to fix a Grammar Problem

Tags: parsing, vb6, grammar, recursive-descent, left-recursion

We have little snippets of vb6 code (the only use a subset of features) that gets wirtten by non-programmers. These are called rules. For the people writing these they are hard to debug so somebody wrote a kind of add hoc parser to be able to evaluete the subexpressions and thereby show better where the problem is.

This addhoc parser is very bad and does not really work woll. So Im trying to write a real parser (because im writting it by hand (no parser generator I could understand with vb6 backends) I want to go with recursive decent parser). I had to reverse-engineer the grammer because I could find anything. (Eventully I found something http://www.notebar.com/GoldParserEngine.html but its LALR and its way bigger then i need)

Here is the grammer for the subset of VB.

```
<Rule>                 ::=  expr rule | e
<Expr>                 ::= ( expr )
                           | Not_List CompareExpr <and_or> expr
                           | Not_List CompareExpr

<and_or>                   ::= Or | And

<Not_List>             ::= Not Not_List | e

<CompareExpr>          ::= ConcatExpr comp CompareExpr
                           |ConcatExpr

<ConcatExpr>           ::= term  term_tail & ConcatExpr
                           |term term_tail

<term>                 ::= factor factor_tail
<term_tail>            ::= add_op term term_tail | e

<factor>               ::= add_op Value | Value
<factor_tail>          ::= multi_op  factor factor_tail | e

<Value>                ::= ConstExpr | function | expr

<ConstExpr>            ::= <bool> | number | string | Nothing
<bool>                 ::= True | False
<Nothing>              ::= Nothing | Null | Empty

<function>             ::= id | id ( ) | id ( arg_list )
<arg_list>             ::= expr , arg_list | expr

<add_op>               ::= + | -
<multi_op>             ::= * | /
<comp>                 ::= > | < | <= | => |  =< | >= |  = | <>
```

All in all it works pretty good here are some simple examples:

```
my_function(1, 2 , 3)
```

looks like

```
(Programm
 (rule
  (expr
   (Not_List)
   (CompareExpr
    (ConcatExpr
     (term
      (factor
       (value
        (function
         my_function
         (arg_list
          (expr
           (Not_List)
           (CompareExpr
            (ConcatExpr (term (factor (value 1))) (term_tail))))
          (arg_list
           (expr
            (Not_List)
            (CompareExpr
             (ConcatExpr (term (factor (value 2))) (term_tail))))
           (arg_list
            (expr
             (Not_List)
             (CompareExpr
              (ConcatExpr (term (factor (value 3))) (term_tail))))
            (arg_list))))))))
     (term_tail))))
  (rule)))
```

Now whats my problem?

if you have code that looks like this `(( true OR false ) AND true)` I have a infinit recursion but the real problem is that in the  `(true OR false) AND true` (after the first `( expr )` ) is understood as only `(true or false)`.

Here is the Parstree:
[image: Parse Tree]

So how to solve this. Should I change the grammer somehow or use some implmentation hack?

Something hard exmplale in case you need it.

```
(( f1 OR f1 ) AND (( f3="ALL" OR f4="test" OR f5="ALL" OR f6="make" OR f9(1, 2) ) AND ( f7>1 OR f8>1 )) OR f8 <> "")
```

Comment: You should probably read the answers to the other three questions on SO tagged `left-recursion`.

Comment: VB6 is hard to parse, mostly due to poor documentation but also due to strangeness in interactions between statements-within-lines and statemenst that span lines.  There are robust VB6 parsers.  See my company's parser:  http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/VisualBasicFrontEnd.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues that I see.

You are treating OR and AND as equal precedence operators. You should have separate rules for OR, and for AND. Otherwise you will the wrong precedence (therefore evaluation) for the expression A OR B AND C.

So as a first step, I'd revise your rules as follows:

```
<Expr>  ::= ( expr )                        
            | Not_List AndExpr Or  Expr   
            | Not_List AndExpr

<AndExpr>  ::=                        
            | CompareExpr And  AndExpr   
            | Not_List CompareExpr
```

Next problem is that you have ( expr ) at the top level of your list.  What if I write:

```
 A AND (B OR C)
```

To fix this, change these two rules:

```
<Expr>  ::= Not_List AndExpr Or Expr   
            | Not_List AndExpr

<Value> ::= ConstExpr | function | ( expr )
```

I think your implementation of Not is not appropriate.  Not is an operator,
just with one operand, so its "tree" should have a Not node and a child which
is the expression be Notted. What you have a list of Nots with no operands.
Try this instead:

```
<Expr>  ::= AndExpr Or Expr   
            | AndExpr

<Value> ::= ConstExpr | function | ( expr ) | Not Value
```

I haven't looked, but I think VB6 expressions have other messy things in them.

If you notice, the style of Expr and AndExpr I have written use *right* recursion to avoid *left* recursion.  You should change your Concat, Sum, and Factor rules to follow a similar style; what you have is pretty complicated and hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

If they are just creating snippets then perhaps VB5 is "good enough" for creating them.  And if VB5 is good enough, the free VB5 Control Creation Edition might be worth tracking down for them to use:

http://www.thevbzone.com/vbcce.htm

You could have them start from a "test harness" project they add snippets to, and they can even test them out.

With a little orientation this will probably prove much more practical than hand crafting a syntax analyzer, and a lot more useful since they can test for more than correct syntax.

Where VB5 is lacking you might include a static module in the "test harness" that provides a rough and ready equivalent of Split(), Replace(), etc:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188007

Comment: VB5CCE may even accept IDE add-ins like MZ-Tools 3.0, and in the end you may make these folks a lot more productive.